# Rails using ActiveJob/Sidekiq does not initiate job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sidekiq

While using ActiveJob with sidekiq,

```
# application.rb
config.active_job.queue_adapter = :sidekiq
```

I made a job using redis.

```
class SubmissionJob < ActiveJob::Base
  queue_as :default

  def perform(*args)
```

While checking through the log, after calling job as

```
SubmissionJob_perform_later args
```

But this doesn't work after giving message when doing `rails s`

```
Enqueued SubmissionJob (Job ID: 63320b9d-de2a-4791-99f6-e58f2adf73d7) to Sidekiq(development_default) with arguments: ["12345", "12346"]
```

when at last, I render the result calling with job_id from redis, the result supposed to be return the arguments, but it only returns empty array, and it seems SubmissionJob never runned.

However, when I call with `perform_now` ,  `SubmissionJob.perform_now args` the function works properly so it seems the method SubmissionJob itself is not the problem.

Where should I start to find problem and what is the possible solution to solve this.

Comment: Quick question -- Did you start sidekiq server by running `bundle exec sidekiq`?

Comment: Sure I did @31piy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved problem.

This was due to Work did not successfully dequeued job from suggested queue. When running the sidekiq, I gave `-q` option.

For example `bundle exec sidekiq -e develop -q develop_submit_job_queue`